# BatchMessagingMessageConverter support headerMapper trusted types

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-boot 2.7.4 and spring-cloud-dependencies 2021.0.4.

I haven't found any solution in spring documentation for add trustedTypes in `BatchMessagingMessageConverter`. I'm using kafka for read messages in batch-mode. If I insert a custom header (my own class) when the consumer read the header return a `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper$NonTrustedHeaderType` and not my class.

I have in my configuration this key to activate batch mode:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.nameBind-in-0.consumer.batch-mode=true
```

I tried in debug to add to headerMapper in `BatchMessagingMessageConverter` the package of my class and all works fine. There is a way to specify my package in configuration?

I followed the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-binder-properties, I created a bean like this:

```java
@Bean("kafkaHeaderMapperCustom")
KafkaHeaderMapper getKafkaHeaderMapperCustom() {
    var defKHM = new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
    defKHM.addTrustedPackages("*");
    return defKHM;
}
```

Specified to key `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName` in configuration but doesn't work, I suppose that configuration is valid for not batch context?

I tried also these properties:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages
spring.json.trusted.packages
```

EDIT - Add example:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaderMapper;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static final String HEADER_KEY = "CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(StreamBridge streamBridge) {
        return args -> {
            var headers = new MessageHeaders(Map.of(HEADER_KEY, new CustomHeaderClass("field1Value", LocalDate.now())));
            headers.get(KafkaHeaders.BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS);
            var message = MessageBuilder.createMessage(new ExampleBrokenHeaderEntity("randomValue", "randomName"), headers);
            streamBridge.send("stackoverflow-example", message);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<List<ExampleBrokenHeaderEntity>>> readFromKafkaBatchMode() {
        return messages -> {
            var brokenHeader = ((ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) messages.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS)).get(0).get(HEADER_KEY);
            System.out.println("BATCH - Class header: " + (brokenHeader != null ? brokenHeader.getClass() : null));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<ExampleBrokenHeaderEntity>> readFromKafkaNoBatchMode() {
        return messages -> {
            var brokenHeader = messages.getHeaders().get(HEADER_KEY);
            System.out.println("NO_BATCH - Class header: " + (brokenHeader != null ? brokenHeader.getClass() : null));
        };
    }

    @Bean("kafkaHeaderMapperCustom")
    public KafkaHeaderMapper getKafkaHeaderMapperBatchMode() {
        var kafkaHeaderMapperCustom = new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
        kafkaHeaderMapperCustom.addTrustedPackages("*");
        return kafkaHeaderMapperCustom;
    }
}
```

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomHeaderClass {

    private String field1;

    private LocalDate field2;

}
```

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class ExampleBrokenHeaderEntity {

    private String type;

    private String name;

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=x.x.x.x:xxxx

spring.cloud.function.definition=readFromKafkaNoBatchMode;readFromKafkaBatchMode

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.readFromKafkaBatchMode-in-0.destination=stackoverflow-example
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.readFromKafkaBatchMode-in-0.group=readFromKafkaBatchMode
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.readFromKafkaBatchMode-in-0.consumer.batch-mode=true

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.readFromKafkaNoBatchMode-in-0.destination=stackoverflow-example
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.readFromKafkaNoBatchMode-in-0.group=readFromKafkaNoBatchMode

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName=kafkaHeaderMapperCustom
```

The output of example is:

```
NO_BATCH - Class header: class com.example.kafka.header.types.CustomHeaderClass
BATCH - Class header: class org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper$NonTrustedHeaderType
```

Comment: Edit the question to show your `application.yml/properties`.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell thanks for the answer, I added a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for the complete example; next time it would be easier to post the whole project someplace to avoid having to copy/paste. It looks like a bug to me; I'll see if I can find a work around. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug; the binder only sets the custom header mapper on a record converter:

```java
private MessageConverter getMessageConverter(
        final ExtendedConsumerProperties<KafkaConsumerProperties> extendedConsumerProperties) {

    MessageConverter messageConverter = BindingUtils.getConsumerMessageConverter(getApplicationContext(),
            extendedConsumerProperties, this.configurationProperties);
    if (messageConverter instanceof MessagingMessageConverter) {
        ((MessagingMessageConverter) messageConverter).setHeaderMapper(getHeaderMapper(extendedConsumerProperties));
    }
    return messageConverter;
}
```

There should be similar code for when the converter is a `BatchMessagingMessageConverter`.

The work around is to define a custom message converter for the batch consumer:

```java
@Bean("batchConverter")
BatchMessageConverter batchConverter(KafkaHeaderMapper kafkaHeaderMapperCustom) {
    BatchMessagingMessageConverter batchConv = new BatchMessagingMessageConverter();
    batchConv.setHeaderMapper(kafkaHeaderMapperCustom);
    return batchConv;
}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.readFromKafkaBatchMode-in-0.consumer.converter-bean-name=batchConverter
```

```
NO_BATCH - Class header: class com.example.demo.So74294156Application$CustomHeaderClass
BATCH - Class header: class com.example.demo.So74294156Application$CustomHeaderClass
```

Please open an issue against Spring Cloud Stream, referencing this question/answer.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I opened this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2550. I promise, next time I'll provide an example committed on GitHub :)

Comment: Hi @GaryRussel ! Thanks for your answer. Any idea why your converter doesn't work for me? 
Bean named 'batchConverter' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.BatchMessagingMessageConverter'

Comment: spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.my-binding.consumer.converter-bean-name: batchConverter

Comment: spring-cloud-stream 3.0.12.RELEASE

Comment: It needs `...consumer.batch-mode=true` to use a batch converter; if that's not the problem, ask a new question with config details. 3.0.x is no longer supported. https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#support

Comment: It does have the consumer.batch-mode=true. My StreamListener is receiving an array of messages without a problem, but the headers ("kafka_batchConvertedHeaders") are very messy.

Comment: Do you want me to open a new question, @GaryRussel ?

Comment: Hey Gary, just opened a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/74948993/3551820